# How can i create the correct JSON data in an Android app required for a Java Jax RS REST POST Api accepting a List of JSON Objects

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a Jax-Rs created REST endpoint as defined below:

```
//It will create the order for the customer who is occupying
    //the table identified by the PathParam tableId
    @Path("/order/{tableId}")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public List<ItemOrder> giveOrder(@PathParam("tableId") int tableId, List<ItemOrder> itemOrderList){

        Customer currentCustomer = Restaurant.getRestaurant().getCustomerArray().get(tableId);

        for (int i = 0; i<itemOrderList.size(); i++){
            currentCustomer.giveOrder(itemOrderList.get(i));
        }
        return itemOrderList;
    }
```

Class ItemOrder has been defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ItemOrder {
    private Item mItem;
    private int mNumberOfPlates;
    .....
......
.....
}
```

Class Item has been defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Item {
    private int mItemId;
    private String mName;
    private float mPrice;
......
......
......
}
```

Now i am trying to send the JSON Post data from an Android client App as follows:

```
//Ordering Menu
        JSONObject itemOrder1Item = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject itemOrder1 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            itemOrder1Item.put("itemId", 11);
            itemOrder1Item.put("itemName","Tea");
            itemOrder1Item.put("itemPrice", 10);
            itemOrder1.put("Item", itemOrder1Item);
            itemOrder1.put("numberOfPlates", 10);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject itemOrder2Item = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject itemOrder2 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            itemOrder2Item.put("itemId", 22);
            itemOrder2Item.put("itemName","Coffee");
            itemOrder2Item.put("itemPrice", 20);
            itemOrder2.put("Item", itemOrder2Item);
            itemOrder2.put("numberOfPlates", 10);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Message",e.getMessage());
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        jsonArray.put(itemOrder1);
        jsonArray.put(itemOrder2);

        JSONObject itemsOrderListObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            itemsOrderListObj.put("itemOrderList", jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HTTPAsyncTask asyncTask = new HTTPAsyncTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),c, null, itemsOrderListObj, "POST");
        asyncTask.execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/restaurant1/webapi/restaurant/waiters/menus/order/2");
    }
```

But it is throwing some error saying the POST data is not correct. While developing the REST Api i have seen that the server is able to accept data as follows:

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "itemId": 11,
            "itemName": "Tea",
            "itemPrice": 10
        },
        "numberOfPlates": 5
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "itemId": 22,
            "itemName": "Coffee",
            "itemPrice": 20
        },
        "numberOfPlates": 5
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "itemId": 33,
            "itemName": "Bread",
            "itemPrice": 30
        },
        "numberOfPlates": 5
    }
]
```

Now how will i be able to create this JSON Data in my Android app.

Need the help badly.

Comment: try using GSON library

Comment: Read about Retrofit and GSON libraries

Comment: Thank you DeKaNszn and Sumit. Have used Gson. DeKaNszn, i am doing this exercise to create a simple example application to showcase both REST Api and Android REST client. Hence have not used Retrofit....

Answer (score 0):

Used GSON. Its pretty simple as follows;

```
List<ItemOrder> itemsOrderListObj = new ArrayList<>();

        itemsOrderListObj.add(new ItemOrder(new Item(11, "Tea", 10), 10));
        itemsOrderListObj.add(new ItemOrder(new Item(22, "Coffee", 20), 10));
        itemsOrderListObj.add(new ItemOrder(new Item(33, "Bread", 30), 10));

        String itemsOrderListStringJSON = new Gson().toJson(itemsOrderListObj);
        Log.i("JSONPOSTDATA", itemsOrderListStringJSON );


        HTTPAsyncTask asyncTask = new HTTPAsyncTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),c, null, itemsOrderListStringJSON, "POST");
        asyncTask.execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/restaurant1/webapi/restaurant/waiters/menus/order/2");
```